# "No connection adapters were found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest

I'm trying to play around with an API from Polygon and I'm getting this pretty long error

```
File "c:\Users\mitch\Desktop\stockmarket\app.py", line 12, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 639, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\mitch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 732, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "{'https://api.polygon.io/v1/open-close/AAPL/2020-10-14?adjusted=true&apiKey={API_key}'}"
```

Here's my app code

```
import os
import requests

url = {
    'https://api.polygon.io/v1/open-close/AAPL/2020-10-14?adjusted=true&apiKey={API_key}'
}

if os.path.isfile('.env'):
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv()

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
else:
    print("error")
```

I'm passing the API key  as a variable from a .env file. I even tried hard coding it into the url and it still got the same error response

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> url = {
...     'https://api.polygon.io/v1/open-close/AAPL/2020-10-14?adjusted=true&apiKey={API_key}'
... }

>>> type(url)
<class 'set'>
```

`requests.get()` is expecting a `str`, not a `set`. Not certain what you were attempting to do here, but you wrapped your actual URL in a `set` and did not actually format it with `API_key`.